# GeoCoordinateWatcher isn't working after migration to WP8

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation, windows-phone-8

I developed a navigation application for windows phone 7.1. It was running fine there. After updating to 8.0 my GeoCoordinateWatcher isnt working anymore. I know that I could use Geolocator instead, but I refuse to do so, because of lack of time.

For my app I read the current position of my watcher to store it for an object instance with location information. When I save my object instance the longitude and latitude are 0.0. Even when I change the position in my emulator still 0.0. The same issue occurs on my other pages, which use GeoCoordinateWatcher. It doesnt work. As I already said, on WP 7.1 - 7.8 it works very well.

```
    public Map()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
        watcher.MovementThreshold = 20;
        watcher.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(watcher_StatusChanged);
        watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);
    }

    void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        if (e.Position.Location.IsUnknown)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please wait while your prosition is determined.");
            return;
        }

        geo.Latitude = e.Position.Location.Latitude;
        geo.Longitude = e.Position.Location.Longitude;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    GeoCoordinateWatcher watch;
public GeoCoordinate loc = null;
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if (watch == null)
    {
        watch = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High)
        {
            MovementThreshold=10
        };
        watch.Start();
        watch.PositionChanged += watch_PositionChanged;
    }
}
void watch_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>LocUpdate(e));
}

void LocUpdate(GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
{
    try
    {
        location = new GeoCoordinate(e.Position.Location.Latitude, e.Position.Location.Longitude);


    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}
```